# ClassNotFoundError in sql DriverNotFound

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;

class MysqlCon{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
//here test is the database name, root is the username and root is the password
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from person");

while(rs.next())
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));

con.close();

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

}
}
```

m working on textpad. i have tried it on eclipse too by adding external jars.
I have added mysql-connector.jar in jre/lib and jre/lib/ext. . . still m getting this exception. why ??? plz help

Comment: If you get an exception, please show the stack trace too.

Comment: You need to add `mysql-connector.jar` to your `CLASSPATH`. So that `DriverManager` can find the Class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Comment: If you are executing via command line then use -cp to add mysql-connector.jar to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at MysqlCon.main(MysqlCon.java:6)

Comment: above is my stackTrace.

Comment: m running mysql in xampp server. what wrong m doing?

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse follow this..

**right click on your project-> build path -> add external archives -> select your jar** 
all ok. run your class.

in cmd follow this..

**c:\your folder>javac -cp your_path_of_mysql-connector.jar MysqlCon.java**

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is not in your build path.

Comment: i followed as u said. . . but now m getting this
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: this exception shows that maybe the password is not correct,but most  frequent reason is that 有

Comment: ok,i got it,the most frequent reason is that you should use Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test","root","root");
 if only your passwd and database is correct, sorry for my poor English